# Toolbar with Immersive Full-Screen Mode

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

Is it possible to use `Immersive Mode` on Android KitKat and Lollipop in combination with a Toolbar?

**Toolbar**

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```

**hide Action Bar** (Toolbar)

```
    // This snippet hides the system bars.
    // https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html
private void hideSystemUI() {
    // Set the IMMERSIVE flag.
    // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the content
    // doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.

    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);

    getSupportActionBar().hide();
}
```

This works fine. But the Toolbar doesn't appear again.

Comment: Hi, did you find the solution? Can you please share?

Answer (score 3):

> Try this

```
 @Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I opened a new issue in the official Google immersive sample project code. Hope they will provide an official way to handle toolbar in immersive mode.

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BasicImmersiveMode/issues/1

Answer (score 1):

This may help others, I have solved using `View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener` here is code snipet

```
--------

 View mDecorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
 mDecorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(mOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener);
-------


hideSystemUI();

---------


 private View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener mOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener = new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
        if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == View.VISIBLE) {
            mToolBar.startAnimation(mSlideDown);
            getSupportActionBar().show();
        } else {
            getSupportActionBar().hide();
            mToolBar.startAnimation(mSlideUp);
        }
    }
};
```

Find complete [sample code](https://github.com/babakothawale/toolbar_immersive_mode)

Comment: I will give it a try. How do the animations look like?

Comment: The animations are same as the default ActionBar hides(scrolls up) and show(scrolls down) in immersive mode.